# sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html on newly created directories in vsFTPd?

Tags: permissions, ftp

I am currently using this for my non-popular website:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

And I have searched many hours on how to make newly created directories and files 775 - I've come across umask and GSID (CHMOD g+s...) stuff, but I don't know how to use those in my `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html`

How do I make `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html` for newly created files/directories in vsftpd? I get these permissions in newly created directories: `drwx------` and files: `-rw-------` which means I can't do anything as a user and I want them to be `(d)rwxrwxr-x`; 775.

EDIT: umask 002 did not work, but I found out my "Owner/group" in my FTP shows as "33 33" on non-newly created directories/files when newly created ones are "1000 1000" what does that mean?

SOLUTION: Editing /etc/vsftpd.conf - making local umask=002, anon_upload_enable=YES, anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES and adding this at the bottom of the file: file_open_mode=0777

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
umask 002
```

And all new files will be created with 775 permission

If you like that the new files groupid will be equal to folder group I'd. You can for example change the folder group to be 1000 as the new files

Comment: It did not work - it's the same, but "owner/group" is 1000/1000 on my new files and directories when my other non-newly created files and directories are at "33 33"

Comment: New files will be created with permission as defined in umask. The files ownership is depend on the user ID of the process which write them.

Comment: So does owner/group not matter in my question? How do umask 002 not work for me then? I typed `umask` and it says 0002 is that why?

Comment: @Zecret *where* did you change `umask`? if you are concerned with files created/uploaded over (vs)ftp, then AFAIK it is the `local_umask` and/or `anon_umask` in `vsftpd.conf` that you will need to modify: see for example [Default owner/permissions of created files via VSFTPD](https://serverfault.com/a/379648)

Comment: Thanks, it worked with editing `local umask=002`, `anon_upload_enable=YES`, `anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES` and adding this at the bottom of the file: `file_open_mode=0777`.

Comment: @Yaron I'm afraid not. The default permissions ***for files*** (before applying any umasks) are ***666***. The default permissions for ***directories*** are ***777***. With `umask 002` you thus get 664 for files (rw-rw-r--) and 775 for directories (drwxrwxr-x).

Comment: @PerDuck yes Yaron meant `umask 000` when I wanted 775, right?

Comment: @Zecret You cannot create files with the `x` bit set by default. Files will always have 666 _minus_ the umask. So `umask 000` will create files with `666`. But I don't know anything about `vsftpd`, though.

Comment: @PerlDuck - thanks for your comment! I think that in this case - files which should be read-able for a web-server -  664 for files (rw-rw-r--) and 775 for directories (drwxrwxr-x) is the right permission. Do you agree?

Comment: @Yaron I think so. Apparently the current umask of the OP's web user is 066 and changing it to (the usual) 022 (group may write) or 002 (group may not write) should work.

Comment: @PerlDuck - Thanks for your comment, I think that you had a typo - did you mean to write: 022 (group may **not** write) or 002 (group may write) ?

Comment: @Yaron. Exactly. Thank you for pointing that out. I find it always tricky to get it right because you have to think "backwards" with the umask.